# How to convert coordinates to BB screen pixels?

Tags: java, google-maps, blackberry, gps, coordinates

I am trying to write a code that draws the road that the user have walked. I can get all the coordinates that user have passed now I have to implement the drawing road. But before doing it I have to know how to pass real world coordinates to BB screen as pixels. Can you give me a little information about it ?

Thank you

Here this the code that I have got all the coordinates of the road.

```
public RoutePaint() {

    locations = new Vector();
    locVector = new ButtonField("Locations Vector",
            ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    locVector.setChangeListener(this);

    pixel.setChangeListener(this);
    add(locVector);
    add(pixel);

    myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS);
    try {
        myProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider) LocationProvider
                .getInstance(myCriteria);

    } catch (LocationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myProvider.setLocationListener(this, 3, -1, -1);



}

public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    point = new Point();
    latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
    altitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getAltitude();
    longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
    velocity = location.getSpeed();
    point.x = latitude;
    point.y = longitude;

    locations.addElement(point);

    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the code to convert coordinates to screen pixels:

```
             XYPoint _xypoint = new XYPoint();
             Coordinates coords = getCoordinates();
         coords.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble((String) _latitude);
         coords.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble((String) _longitude);


         convertWorldToField(coords,_xypoint);
             int x = _xypoint.x;
             int y = _xypoint.y;
```

where we assume that latitude and longitude are saved in variables _latitude and _longitude respectively.integer variable x and y consists converted screen pixels from coordinates.